# How to load parent component as child component of its child component in angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular, parent-child

I have a parent component in angular2 which loads few components as :

```
<component-property-editor component-name="array-obj-editor" [(component-model)]="selectedCol.model.data"></component-property-editor>
```

the above statement load `array-obj-editor` component along with its model.

Basically it is a parent component which accepts component name & madel as input and then renders its view.

So far I am able to render the components correctly.

using DynamicComponentLoader as below:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Type, Input, DynamicComponentLoader, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {ArrayObjEditorComponent} from './editors/array-obj-editor/array-obj-editor.component';
import {FontSelectEditorComponent} from './editors/font-select-editor/font-select-editor.component';    
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'component-property-editor',
  templateUrl: 'component-property-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['component-property-editor.component.css'],
})
export class ComponentPropertyEditorComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target;
    @Input('component-name') componentName: string;
    @Input('component-info') componentInfo: string;
    @Input('component-model') componentModel: Object;

    typesRegister: Type[] = [ArrayObjEditorComponent,FontSelectEditorComponent];
    keysRegister: string[] = ['array-obj-editor','font-select-editor'];
    constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader) { }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('Property Editor' + this.componentName + " Loading");
        let componentIndex = this.keysRegister.indexOf(this.componentName);
        this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(this.typesRegister[componentIndex],
            this.target).then(ref =>{ ref.instance.componentModel = this.componentModel; });
            console.log('Property Editor...' + this.componentName + " Loaded");
    }
}
```

But its a recursive process . i.e. I want to load `component-property-editor` i.e. parent component in the loaded components.

I tried including `component-property-editor` as a directive in `array-obj-editor`

But its not working.It shows below error:

> Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'ArrayObjEditorComponent'

Comment: Can you please provide a Plunker. I find this to confusion and have no idea what the actual problem is. You definitely can't add a parent as a child. You can have a child component of the same type as the parent component but this then is not a parent.

Comment: my parent component accepts two inputs. selector and model of component to render. so when parent is rendering a child component, inside that child component I again want to render another component by passing the input and model. @GünterZöchbauer